# Making an instance method inaccessible from a subclass

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, visibility

Given:

```
class Base
  def foo
    puts 'foo!!!'
  end
end

class Ball < Base
end
```

I want:

1. `Ball.new.foo` to return an error: `No Method Found`.
2. `Base.new.foo` to return: `foo!!!`.

My attempts are:

- I could do `protected def foo`, so that 1. works. However this doesn't work for 2.
- I could do it just like as this given above, so that 2. works. However 1. doesn't work.

Any ideas how to make both 1. and 2. work?

**Background of the Problem**

I have an `ApplicationController` action `def routing_error` that handles all remaining undefined routes. The problem with this is all all of the other controllers that inherits `ApplicationController` also inherits that action, in which I wanted it to be not. I could create a separate controller with just the action `def routing_error` but I feel it is overkill, and is just wondering first if there is another way to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do:

```
class Ball < Base
  undef_method :foo
end
```

If you want to undefine the method for many classes and you don't want to write the code like the above for each of them, then create a class in between.

```
class Dummy < Base
  undef_method :foo
end

class Base < Dummy
end

class Base2 < Dummy
end

...
```

Comment: This solved my question. However, as for the root of my problem, this will need me to put `undef_method :foo` to all my controllers. Maybe, I could do it like this for now. Thanks!

Comment: `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass < ApplicationController }.each { |c| c.send :undef_method, :foo }`

Comment: @mudasobwa, thanks! this will help too :) I just need to make sure to call this line at the end of all the application code.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario You don't need to do that. See my edit.